Unreal engine5 GameHasEnded() Function does not working
This is all code related to calling GameHasEnded
In the debug, the if statement in the PlayerController  goes in just fine, but the GameHasEnded is not being called at all.
The content of GameHasEnded is simply a call to UE_LOG and a timer of about 3 seconds to restart the game.
     float AShooterCharacter::TakeDamage(float DamageAmount, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* EventInstigator, AActor* DamageCauser)
{
    float DamageToApply = Super::TakeDamage(DamageAmount,DamageEvent,EventInstigator,DamageCauser);
    
    DamageToApply = FMath::Min(Health,DamageToApply);
    Health -= DamageToApply;
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Health : %f"),Health);
    // if(Health <= 0)
    // {
    //  Health -= DamageToApply;
    // }

    if(IsDead())
    {
        ASimpleShooterGameModeBase* GameMode = GetWorld()->GetAuthGameMode<ASimpleShooterGameModeBase>();
        if(GameMode != nullptr)
        {
            GameMode->PawnKilled(this);
        }

        DetachFromControllerPendingDestroy();
        GetCapsuleComponent()->SetCollisionEnabled(ECollisionEnabled::NoCollision);
    }

    return DamageToApply;
}


void AKillEmAllGameMode::PawnKilled(APawn* PawnKilled)
{
    Super::PawnKilled(PawnKilled);
    
    APlayerController* PlayerController = Cast<APlayerController>(PawnKilled->GetController());

    if(PlayerController != nullptr)
    {
        PlayerController->GameHasEnded(nullptr,false);
    }

}

void AShooterPlayerController::GameHasEnded(AActor* EndGameFocus, bool bIsWinner)
{
    Super::GameHasEnded(EndGameFocus, bIsWinner);

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("End"));

    GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(RestartTimer,this,&APlayerController::RestartLevel,RestartDelay);
}

First, I tried debugging it: it gets inside the if statement, but not inside the GameHasEnded     function.
Secondly, I searched for GameHasEnded and found that I should call getdefaultpawnclassforcontroller and override it by replacing it with virtual, but this is not what I wanted because it is Read-Only and returns a Pawn.
Third, I checked to make sure that the Blueprint specified in the GameMode, WorldSetting, and ProjectSettings was entered. I confirmed that it was, and that it was correctly entered.
The fourth thing I checked is the most suspicious, I changed the 'PlayerControllerClass' in 'GameMode' to 'BP_ShooterPlayerController', but when I run it, it spawns a 'PlayearController'.
I googled 'getdefaultpawnclassforcontroller' but it didn't work, so this is in line with the second point.
Please help
